# Should the comma be inside or outside of the quotation marks?

Tags: commas, quotations

Say I have a sentence like

> The discovery of the "exoplanet", a type of planet that resides outside of our solar system, shocked the researchers.

Should the comma be outside of the quotation marks because the comma has to help form the appositive "a type of planet that resides outside of our solar system?

Comment: Outside is more logical and is how it is normally done in Britain, Australia, etc.. Inside is the American way.

Comment: Not really relevant, but there are two uses of "outside of" here that could be simplified to "outside".

Answer (score 1):

The [AP style](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/subject_specific_writing/journalism_and_journalistic_writing/ap_style.html), most commonly used in the US, suggests that the comma should always stay inside the quotation.

> Commas and periods go within quotation marks. Example: “I did nothing wrong,” he said. She said, “Let’s go to the Purdue game.”

[University of Oxford style guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf) (which pertains to BrE) makes it dependent on whether the punctuation mark was a part of the original quote:

> If the quote would have required punctuation in its original form, place the punctuation inside the quotation marks. (If it is unclear, try writing the whole sentence out without quotation marks and ‘he said’ etc, and replicate the resulting punctuation.) (...) Place any punctuation which does not belong to the quote outside the quotation marks (except closing punctuation if the end of the quote is also the end of the sentence).

Note however that Oxford also uses single quotation marks to denote the outer quote, and double quotation marks to denote inner quotes. So if you're already using double quotes, it's probably better not to mix and match styles and follow the AP guide.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. I meant should the comma be outside of the quotation marks because to separate the phrase "a type of planet that resides outside of our solar system". Thanks

Comment: To combine double quotes with BrE isn't necessarily to "mix and match". There are other BrE style guides that recommend double quotes for the outer marks and single quotes for innter quotes.  The great majority of BrE newspapers and magazines use double quotes as their primary quotation marks.  (Novels usually use single quotes.)

Comment: Sorry let me clarify myself. I know that commas can be used to set off a certain part of the sentence as non-essential. I am wondering if I had a sentence like the one I put for my question, would I have to put the comma outside of the quotation marks to indicate that "a type...system" is a non-essential phrase or inside to follow the AP style? Thanks

Comment: Do you have an AP Style example for putting a single word in quotation marks as in the OP's sentence? The examples given in this answer are a bit different because they're quoting sentences.

Comment: When you use quotation marks to indicate literal text, as in 'The company was renamed from "Acme Inc." to "Acme Ltd"', it's vital that the text inside the quotes should not be modified. Publishing style guides often assume that quotation marks are being used for direct speech in novels, where the exact placement doesn't affect the meaning ("Go West, young man," he said) - but even there, the BrE convention feels much more logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

The common usage is to put the comma inside, and that’s fine for most writing even if it seems a little odd. People are used to it.

However, in technical writing where adding or changing punctuation could alter the meaning of the quote, put it outside. For instance, here on ELL we often discuss punctuation itself, so it’s important in those cases that quotes not be altered *in any way* by the discussion around them.

More important trying the choice itself Is being consistent in a given piece of writing; any exceptions in either direction will look like errors.